# why IO::Pty and Expect modules can help to solute open2 's block?

Tags: perl, ipc

the perl's open2 perldoc : http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html
descript that :

> his whole affair is quite dangerous, as you may block forever. It assumes it's going to talk to something like bc ....
>   ...
>   The IO::Pty and Expect modules from CPAN can help with this, as they provide a real tty (well, a pseudo-tty, actually), which gets you back to line buffering in the invoked command again.

but I don't understand why IO::Pty and Except modules can solute the open2's problem?

by the way , does the FileHandler return from open2 can be noblocking readed ?

very thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you used buffered I/O, data is not sent through the file handle until the buffer is full. This is different from terminal I/O where a line is sent once the user hits the Enter key. So if you are writing a program to interact with a program as if it were a user, buffered I/O can cause problems. For example, your program can send a line of data expecting that the other side will receive it and output a reply. However, if that line of data is still sitting in the output buffer when you wait for the reply you will deadlock - your program is waiting for a reply from a program which is waiting for your input which is still sitting in the output buffer.

Using a pty to interact with the program allows you to use line buffering (in both directions) so data is sent once a newline is encountered in the stream.

Also, any file handle can be read from in a non-blocking fashion - just use `select` to determine if there is data available on that file handle.

This article might help explain things: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

Comment: ok,very thank you ! but when I use pipe() function to create a pipe , I found that each time I write a line in the INPUT side , the OUTPUT side will can read the line immediately, does this mean the pipe is line buffering too ?

Comment: Buffering occurs at the stdio level (where you access things through file handles), not the file descriptor level. In order to explain what you are seeing I would have to see your code.

Comment: parent process open a file , then fork a child , does child and parent share the file's stdio level buffer ?

Comment: No. The child's buffer will be a copy of the parent's at the time of the fork, but they will be independent buffers. However, my experiments show that they share the same file descriptor. So if one process reads from the file it will affect what the other process sees when it reads through the file handle.